# Heroku build failing when restoring NuGet packages

Tags: heroku, f#, mono

I'm nearly there getting my F# project to compile under Heroku.
Unfortunately I've hit a problem.

It attempts to restore the nuget packages I get the error:

```
Target Build:
    Project "/tmp/build_7ab344f5-4cd2-4af5-92cd-814069a4af70/NancyFirstProject/NancyFirstProject.fsproj" (default target(s)):
        Target RestorePackages:
            Executing: mono --runtime=v4.0.30319 /tmp/build_7ab344f5-4cd2-4af5-92cd-814069a4af70/.nuget/NuGet.exe install "" -source ""   -RequireConsent -solutionDir "/tmp/build_7ab344f5-4cd2-4af5-92cd-814069a4af70/"

The specified path is not of a legal form (empty).
```

I've committed the NuGet.exe and all related NuGet files that are under the .NuGet folder along with my project.

NOTE:  The project was created under VS2013.  It builds and runs fine under Xamarin Studio

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: what version of mono?

Comment: I'm using the buildpack from here:
https://github.com/aktowns/mono3-buildpack.git

I don't really understand the buildpack syntax but there's this line that is picking up the fsc.exe compiler in the compiler:

"#!/bin/sh\n$1/$MONO3_VM_VENDOR/mono3/bin/mono $1/$MONO3_VM_VENDOR/mono3/lib/mono/4.5/fsc.exe \"\$@\""

Comment: The output from Heroku has the version info which is:
XBuild Engine Version 3.0.7.0
Mono, Version 3.0.7.0

Comment: and what version of F#?

Comment: Version 3.0 of F#.  I can't get Xamarin Studio to work with 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

do you have a .sln file for your solution? NuGet needs to find the .sln file to perform package restore. And in older version of NuGet, such error will be raised if .sln file cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced exactly the same problem. Finally, I've disabled NuGet package restore as a build step and decided to run restore separately:

```
wget http://nuget.org/nuget.exe
chmod +x nuget.exe
mono --runtime=v4.0 nuget.exe restore SolutionName.sln
```